# Identify connection between two columns and insert corresponding values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table which you can also find in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6b4322/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    Eventtype TEXT,
    CampaignID TEXT,
    Product TEXT,
    Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Products
(Eventtype, CampaignID, Product, Quantity)
VALUES 

("Event_01", "9857", NULL, "500"),
("Event_01", "5504", NULL, "670"),
("Event_01", "4589", NULL, "950"),
("Event_01", "77801", NULL, "750"),

("Event_02", "9857", "Product A", "300"),
("Event_03", "9857", "Product A", "250"),
("Event_02", "77801", "Product A", "350"),
("Event_03", "77801", "Product A", "150"),

("Event_02", "5504", "Product B", "270"),
("Event_03", "5504", "Product B", "850"),
("Event_02", "4589", "Product B", "420"),
("Event_03", "4589", "Product B", "630");
```

I use the following query:

```
Select Eventtype, CampaignID, Product, Quantity
FROM Products
WHERE Product = "Product B";
```

All this works fine so far.

---

`Event_01` only has a `CampaignID`. 
`Event_02` and `Event_03` have a `CampaignID` and `Products`.

Now I want that if I select `Product B` in the query the corresponding values on `CampaignID` level for `Event_01` are inserted into the results.

Basically, `Event_02` and `Event_03` should be used to identify that `Product B` is connected to a certain `CampaignID` and then the `quantity` for this `CampaignID` in `Event_01` is displayed:

The desired result should look like this:

```
Eventtype         CampaignID         Product         Quantity
Event_01          4589               NULL               950
Event_01          5504               NULL               670
Event_02          4589               Product B          420
Event_02          5504               Product B          270
Event_03          4589               Product B          630
Event_04          5504               Product B          850
```

How do I have to modify my query to achieve this result?

Comment: Can `Event_01` have the same `CampaignID`?

Comment: Why the record `("Event_01", "5504", "NULL", "900")` is included into the output whereas `("Event_01", "5504", "NULL", "500")` is not? it has the same `Eventtype` and `CampaignID`...

Comment: @Michi . . . (1) Your first `GROUP BY` query is malformed.  It has 4 unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` and only 3 in the `GROUP BY`.  (2) Why are you using `"NULL"` as a string instead of `NULL` the SQL keyword?  (3) What happened to the first row for event 5504?  (4) Your results seem to depend on an ordering of the table, but SQL tables represent UNORDERED sets.  There is no ordering unless a column has that information.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thanks for the info and sorry for the mess. I changed my data a bit so it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280758/use-results-from-first-query-as-criteria-for-second-query) question the solution is:

```
SELECT Eventtype, CampaignID, Product, Quantity
FROM Products
WHERE 
CampaignID IN
   (Select CampaignID
    FROM Products
    WHERE Product = "Product B")
 GROUP BY 1,2;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6b4322/1