# Use results from first query as criteria for second query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL table which you can also find in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f2974/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    Supplier TEXT,
    Product TEXT,
    Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Products
(Supplier, Product, Quantity)
VALUES 

("Supplier_01", "Product A", "500"),
("Supplier_05", "Product A", "300"),
("Supplier_09", "Product A", "250"),

("Supplier_05", "Product B", "900"),
("Supplier_06", "Product B", "270"),
("Supplier_02", "Product B", "850"),
("Supplier_05", "Product B", "950"),
("Supplier_10", "Product B", "630");
```

I currently use the following query for it:

```
SELECT Supplier, Product, Quantity
FROM Products
WHERE Product = "Product B";
```

---

However, now I want to use part of the results from the query above as `WHERE` criteria for a second query. 
 Basically, I want that all `Suppliers` which exist for `Product B` are used for the `WHERE` criteria for `Product A`. 
 Something like this:

```
SELECT Supplier, Product, Quantity
FROM Products
WHERE Product = "Product A"
AND Supplier EXISTS IN
   (SELECT Supplier
    FROM Products
    WHERE Product = "Product B") table_01;
```

In the end the desired result should look like this:

```
Supplier             Product          Quantity
Supplier_05          Product A         300
Supplier_02          Product B         850
Supplier_05          Product B         900
Supplier_06          Product B         270
Supplier_10          Product B         630
```

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: . . Your query is malformed.  You have unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  Hence, the question doesn't make sense, because the results from the query are arbitrary.

Comment: We have very different definitions of 'works fine' !!!! :-(

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I deleted the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there:

```sql
SELECT Supplier, Product, Quantity
FROM Products
WHERE Supplier IN
   (SELECT Supplier
    FROM Products
    WHERE Product = "Product B")
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2,1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Exaclty. what I needed. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f2974/22

Comment: but your desired results are different @Michi

Comment: I edited the answer. Now they are the desired result. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f2974/34

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use below script. `INNER JOIN` can be used for filtering a query.

```
SELECT A.SUPPLIER, A.PRODUCT, A.QUANTITY
  FROM (SELECT A.SUPPLIER, A.PRODUCT, A.QUANTITY
         FROM PRODUCTS A) A
   INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SUPPLIER
                 FROM PRODUCTS
                WHERE PRODUCT = "Product B") B
      ON B.SUPPLIER = A.SUPPLIER
```

[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f2974/17)